# A nice display of hillshade and my geologic map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, color, transparency-opacity, display, hillshade

i want to create a nice hillshade map covered by a grid or RGB map, with similar colour results  in ArcMap like this:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in ArcGis without transparency settings which fades colours, and not QGIS, or GlobalMapper?

More like a blend in, described in various threads but with ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an RGB map, you can use the pansharpening option in the symbology (RGB composite) of your RGB, selecting the Hillshade instead of a panchromatic image.

Comment: I made a 3 band RGB layer, but i cannot find the option in symbology for deselcting panchromatic. There is only strechted, RGB composite and colormap. Any hints? :)

Comment: when you are in RGB composite, go down and you'll find it. It is often hidden because the window is too small.

Comment: Ok, ive found the option. But when i insert the hillshade, the map jst turns blank. What can that be? resolution or size, pixel deepth?

Comment: (+1) The pan-sharpening approach is described in a couple of ESRI blogs at http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/01/18/combining-colored-and-grayshade-rasters-with-high-fidelity/ and http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/03/08/an-alternative-to-overlaying-layer-tints-on-hillshades/.